# How does virtualbox get the network configurations?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, dns, centos

I am installing `CentOS 7` on `virtualbox`. On "Network & Host Name" screen:

[image]

When toggle the "OFF" to "ON", I can see the IP, DNS, netmask are all configured:

[image]

I am curious about how does `virtualbox` get all the network configurations. What happen when toggling the "OFF" to "ON"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way VirtualBox configures networking in guests is by not only emulating the networking hardware associated with the VM, but it also creates a layer in between `Host` and `Guest` where it emulates a router.

The "Router" that VirtualBox emulates has settings which can be configured using the `Virtual Machine Manager` and when set to use its own DHCP server, the emulated router pushes settings to the client, as if the client was situated on a physical network using DHCP.

When toggling the `Guest` On/Off switch, it only applies to the `Guest` as it would if you were to setup CentOS on a physical machine, enabling and disabling the interface.

Comment: I am using `NAT` mode. But why the `Guest` can't connect to internet? Executing `curl google.com`, and the output is "`curl(7): Failed tp connect to ...: Network is unreachable`".

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't tell CentOS to autostart networking. in which case, run `sudo systemctl status network` to check the status of networking, and if the service is in the stopped state, run `sudo systemctl start network` to start it.

Comment: Doesn't seem this cause. The status is `Active: active(exited) since .....`. Is this state right?

Comment: what's the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: Because I can't copy easy from VM, so I catch [screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/SZuf4IF.jpg) for the `ip addr`. Sorry for the inconveience.

Comment: What is the output of: `sudo systemctl -l status network`?

Comment: `systemctl -l status network` output: [screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/rBBpnAH.jpg).

Comment: It looks like CentOS can't load/didn't finish loading networking in, and is having trouble with that

Comment: Why does this occur? Do I need re-install the OS?

Comment: I'm not sure. best thing to do would be to reload CentOS

Comment: The root cause is found in this [discussion](http://superuser.com/questions/919618/why-cant-the-guest-of-virtualbox-connect-to-network).

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the NAT mode of Virtualbox, an internal DHCP server is launched for the guests.

According to the doc, (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat) the first card receives an IP in the subnet 10.0.2.0, the second in 10.0.3.0 and so on. This network can be modified (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat), but must be different of the host subnet.

Answer (score 0):

When you toggle on/off, you're enabling and disabling an active link for interface of the VM. VirtualBox reports the config for the interface. It doesn't matter whether it be picking up the conifg from DHCP or it has a statically assigned IP.